# How do I get my files in alphabetical order?

Tags: 16.04

Screenshot when I try to click a link to upload something:

[image: Screenshot when I try to click a link to upload something]

I can not upload my pictures and are in order, but when I try uploading something my folders and including the files are all over the place. They aren't in order. I'm new to this so i have no idea how to fix it. Sorry for that.

Comment: In which context are the files not listed in order? When you use the _Files_ application? When you list them in terminal? If the latter, which command do you use?

Comment: Command? I have everything in alphabetical order, but my computer somehow through it out of whack.

Comment: Only when i try uploading though.

Comment: And which application do you use for uploading? From the screenshot you link to it looks like the folders are sorted by last modified time. Have you tried to click the _Name_ header?

Comment: Name Header? The folder I was in?

Comment: Tried to clarify in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *File Upload* window there is a *Name* column, where the files/folders are listed, and a *Modified* column where the last modified time is stated.

[image]

To view the files/folders alphabetically, click *Name* (surrounded with a red 'circle' above).

Comment: I see. So what do I do? I tried clicking name and goes to the closet folder.

Comment: @NakajimaAtsushi: Do you see that the sort order changed when you clicked _Name_? (I suppose you proceed to the folder where the file you want to upload is located.)